# unordered_map for custom class does not cause error when inserting the same key

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I'm trying to figure out some points on using `unordered_map` for custom class. Below are the codes I use to take exercise where I define a simple class `Line`. I'm confused that why the insertion of `Line2` in `main()` does not make the program outputs `insert failed` when the value of `m` for `Line1` and `Line2` are both `3`. Note since I only compare the first value (i.e. `m`) in the `operator==` function in `class Line`, thus `Line1` and `Line2` in this code should have the same key. Shouldn't the insertion of an already existed key be invalid? Could some one explain why to me? Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#include<unordered_map>                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

using namespace std;                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
class Line {                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  float m;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  float c;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

  Line() {m = 0; c = 0;}                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  Line(float mInput, float cInput) {m = mInput; c = cInput;}                                                                                                                                                                               
  float getM() const {return m;}                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  float getC() const {return c;}                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  void setM(float mInput) {m = mInput;}                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  void setC(float cInput) {c = cInput;}                                                                                                                                                                                                    

  bool operator==(const Line &anotherLine) const                                                                                                                                                                                           
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      return (m == anotherLine.m);                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

namespace std                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  template <>                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  struct hash<Line>                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    size_t operator()(const Line& k) const                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        // Compute individual hash values for two data members and combine them using XOR and bit shifting                                                                                                                                 
        return ((hash<float>()(k.getM()) ^ (hash<float>()(k.getC()) << 1)) >> 1);                                                                                                                                                          
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  };                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  unordered_map<Line, int> t;                                                                                                                                                                                                              

  Line line1 = Line(3.0,4.0);                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  Line line2 = Line(3.0,5.0);                                                                                                                                                                                                              

  t.insert({line1, 1});                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  auto x = t.insert({line2, 2});                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  if (x.second == false)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    cout << "insert failed" << endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                       

  for(unordered_map<Line, int>::const_iterator it = t.begin(); it != t.end(); it++)                                                                                                                                                        
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    Line t = it->first;                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    cout << t.m << " " << t.c << "\n" ;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

  return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

Comment: Your operator == is only used on a collision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `hash` and `operator ==` must satisfy a consistency requirement that they currently violate. When two objects are equal according to `==`, their hash codes *must* be equal according to `hash`. In other words, while non-equal objects may have the same hash code, equal objects must have the same hash code:

```
size_t operator()(const Line& k) const  {
    return hash<float>()(k.getM());
}
```

Since you compare only one component for equality, and ignore the other component, you need to change your hash function to use the same component that you use to decide the equality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm confused that shouldn't the `insert` function of unordered_map decide whether a key is already existed only by checking the return value of `operator==`? I think I make the mistake because I'm not very clear about the function of  `operator==` or comparator in unordered_map. Could you explain more? Thanks!

Comment: @ROBOTAI - If the object ends up in an empty hash slot, there is no collision and so no need to compare anything.

Comment: @BoPersson Cool! That's the point that I missed. So `insert` firstly check the collision of hash, if there is collision, then use `operator==` to check the equality. If not equal, then use chaining to avoid collision. Is this understanding correct? Thanks!

Comment: @ROBOTAI Yes, this is exactly how it works. Operator `==` is used only to resolve ties on hash collisions.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Got it! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

you are using both the values of "m" and "c" in you hash, so  2 "Line" instances would have the same key if both their "m" and "c" are equal, which is not the case in your example. So if you do this :

```
Line line1 = Line(3.0,4.0);                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Line line2 = Line(3.0,4.0);                                                                                                                                                                                                              

t.insert({line1, 1});                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
auto x = t.insert({line2, 2});                                                                                                                                                                                                           
if (x.second == false)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  cout << "insert failed" << endl;
```

you'll see that it will print "insert failed"

Answer (score 0):

You can always use custom function to compare the keys upon insertion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class Line {
private:
    float m;
    float c;
public:
    Line() { m = 0; c = 0; }
    Line(float mInput, float cInput) { m = mInput; c = cInput; }
    float getM() const { return m; }
    float getC() const { return c; }
};


struct hash
{
    size_t operator()(const Line& k) const 
    {
        return ((std::hash<float>()(k.getM()) ^ (std::hash<float>()(k.getC()) << 1)) >> 1);
    }
};

// custom key comparison
struct cmpKey
{
    bool operator() (Line const &l1, Line const &l2) const
    {
        return l1.getM() == l2.getM();
    }
};


int main()
{ 

    std::unordered_map<Line, int, hash, cmpKey> mymap; // with custom key comparisom

    Line line1 = Line(3.0, 4.0);
    Line line2 = Line(4.0, 5.0);
    Line line3 = Line(4.0, 4.0);

    auto x = mymap.insert({ line1, 1 });
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "element inserted: " << x.second << std::endl;
    x = mymap.insert({ line2, 2 });
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "element inserted: " << x.second << std::endl;
    x = mymap.insert({ line3, 3 });
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "element inserted: " << x.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
element inserted: true
element inserted: true
element inserted: false
```